# How to send message to multiple queues?

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

How to send message to multiple queues in C# using the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ client?
I.e. something like RabbitMQ fanout: when publisher send and message received by multiple queues. I use ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.14.3 in Docker and then I need to work with AWS ActiveMQ.

My idea is: a consumer app connects to a system and creates its own queue, a publisher app should publish to multiple queues. Also, the queues set dynamically changes, f.e. some app disconnects from system and its queue should be deleted.

Comment: I use 5.14.3 in Docker and then I need to work with AWS ActiveMQ

Comment: I have found the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ. Is any better?

Comment: "Better" is really relative to the details of your specific use-case. It's not possible for me to say what client may be better with the details you've provided.

Comment: Is the publisher always sending messages to the same destination or does that change as well?

Comment: Publisher sends messages to all destinations, every consumer reads its own queue, acked and react on the message. Also, any consumer can be publisher and publish messages to all queues etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ "Classic" supports a couple approaches to solve for this:

1. [Composite Queue (client-side)](https://activemq.apache.org/composite-destinations) -- producer sends message to multiple destinations, simply by using a comma between them.  producer.send("queue1,queue2,queue3");
2. [Virtual Destination (server-side)](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations) -- broker routing rule(s) define one or more routing behaviors. You can move, or copy message(s) to one or more destinations and optionally filter messages.

Note: There is a server-side Virtual Destination also called 'Composite Destination', not to be confused with the client-side.

Comment: In same cases I can have >=100  destination queues. What is the best way to send msg to these queues? I can get queue list, then send msg in loop M times combinig by N  queues .

Comment: Sounds like you want server-side pub+sub with queues for subsribers. See: Virtual Topics.

Comment: Does Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ also support composite queues like the OpenWire JMS client does?